# Is the libmysqlclient version core requirement actually required?

Tags: 10

So it's been a while since I was doing things with Drupal. For a number of reasons, I decided to put my toe back in the water and install Drupal 10 on my hosting service. All went well, or I thought it did. The status report post-install showed this.

> 10.5.20-MariaDB-cll-lve-log
> The libmysqlclient driver version 3.1.21 is less than the minimum required version. Upgrade to libmysqlclient version 5.5.3 or up, or alternatively switch mysql drivers to MySQLnd version 5.0.9 or up.

Of course, I contacted my hosting service. Their reply was, essentially, that can't be upgraded on a Shared Service and I have to go to a VPS or Dedicated Hosting. They linked me to their installed software list for shared servers.

How much critical is the error in the status report?

- Litespeed: 6.0.12
- Codeguard: included to all Shared plans
- cPanel: 102
- cURL: 7.19.7
- CXS: installed on all Shared servers
- Git: enabled
- HTTP/2: supported
- Imagick module: 3.7.0
- IonCube PHP Loader: 12.0.2
- Mod_Rewrite: enabled
- Mod_Security: enabled
- MariaDB: 10.5
- Node.js: 6.17, 8.17, 9.11, 10.24, 11.15, 12.22, 14.20
- Mysqli Support: enabled
- Perl: 5.10.1
- PHP: 5.6, 7.0-7.4, 8.0, 8.1
- PostgreSQL: 8.4.20
- Python: 2.7, 3.3 - 3.9
- Rails: 2.3.18
- Ruby: 1.8 - 2.7
- ZendGuard Loader: 4.1

Comment: Are you asking if the requirements are really requirements?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an idiot - I guess I am. When I was installing (using Softalicious), it failed because of another dependency (PHP level. It asked if I wanted to enable a higher version, which I did, and it continued to install. The libmysqlclient error didn't stop the install. I know no install script is perfect, and can't cover every dependency. But there are dependencies and dependencies. Some impact function in a black and white way, some impact performance. I figured I'd ask which this was. Apologies for what may well be a dumb question :-).

Comment: That error is given from the installer, so the libmysqlclient error did stop the install. The *utf8mb4* character encoding is required by Drupal core, and that is only handled with more recent versions of the *libmysqlclient* library.

Comment: @apaderno My thanks indeed. I wondered - however, Softalicious reported completed install, with no errors, and at the end I did have a Drupal site I could log in to and see/ use the admin menus (on an admin account). So _something_ appeared to install.

Comment: For information, in case anyone finds it of use, the issue was resolved and the error cleared by changing the PHP library from libmysqlclient to MySQLnd - that is, enabling nd_pdo_mysql instead of pdo_mysql. My thanks to everyone who dropped in to assist :-).

Answer (score 4):

The issue was resolved and the error cleared by changing the PHP library from libmysqlclient to MySQLnd - that is, enabling nd_pdo_mysql instead of pdo_mysql.

Comment: Thanks bro. I had a problem and it seems it is gone by your help.

Comment: Note for noobs like me: enabling nd_pdo_mysql instead of pdo_mysql is done inside the "Select PHP Version" tool of cPanel (also called PHP Selector)

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the library to nd_dpo_mysql in CPanel as suggested, and got an error until I cleared all caches, including the LSCache for LiteSpeed.  Perhaps obvious for some, but for those like me that do site maintenance infrequently, a useful reminder.